# implement iterator on every elements of value containers against each key of map using boost iterator

Tags: c++, boost-iterators

How to implement an iterator of just on values of a map/unordered_map using boost::iterator_adaptor? I've tried following code but it does not work because of the line with comment. 
**Is there a solution to avoid the problem?**

**The question here is slightly different from map_values adapter example shown in boost code as here the value field in map is another container like list or vector and the requirement here is to iterate over all elements of those lists for every key of the map. 
The deref of iterator is of type of value_type of those list/vector.The end of iterator is the end of list of last key**

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>


class DS {
public:
    DS() : _map() {}

    ~DS() {
        for (Map::iterator it = _map.begin(); it != _map.end(); ++it) {
            delete (it->second);
        }
    }

    void add(int key_, const std::vector< int > &value_)
    {
        IntList *ptr = new IntList(value_);
        assert(ptr);

        _map.insert(Map::value_type(key_, ptr));
    }

private:
    typedef std::vector< int > IntList;
    typedef boost::unordered_map< int, IntList* > Map;

    Map      _map;

public:
    class KeyIter : public boost::iterator_adaptor< KeyIter,
                                                    Map::const_iterator,
                                                    int,
                                                    boost::forward_traversal_tag,
                                                    int>
    {
    public:
        KeyIter() : KeyIter::iterator_adaptor_() {}

    private:

        friend class DS;
        friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

        explicit KeyIter(Map::const_iterator it) : KeyIter::iterator_adaptor_(it) {}
        explicit KeyIter(Map::iterator       it) : KeyIter::iterator_adaptor_(it) {}

        int        dereference() const { return this->base()->first; }
    };

    class ValueIter : public boost::iterator_adaptor< ValueIter,
                                                      Map::const_iterator,
                                                      int,
                                                      boost::forward_traversal_tag,
                                                      int>
    {
    public:
        ValueIter()
                : ValueIter::iterator_adaptor_()
                , _lIt()
        {}

    private:
        friend class DS;
        friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

        explicit ValueIter(Map::const_iterator it)
                : ValueIter::iterator_adaptor_(it)
                , _lIt()
                , _mIt(it)
        {
            IntList *pt = it->second; // <<-- issue here is I can't find if I've already reached the end of the map
            if (pt) {
                _lIt = it->second->begin();
            }
        }

        int                dereference() const { return *_lIt; }
        void               increment()
        {
            if (_lIt == _mIt->second->end()) {
                ++_mIt;
                _lIt = _mIt->second->begin();
            } else {
                ++_lIt;
            }
        }

        IntList::iterator        _lIt;
        Map::const_iterator      _mIt;
    };

    KeyIter       beginKey() const { return KeyIter(_map.begin()); }
    KeyIter       endKey()   const { return KeyIter(_map.end());  }
    ValueIter     beginValue() const { return ValueIter(_map.begin()); }
    ValueIter     endValue()   const { return ValueIter(_map.end());   }
};





int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    DS ds;

    std::vector< int > v1;
    v1.push_back(10);
    v1.push_back(30);
    v1.push_back(50);

    ds.add(90, v1);

    std::vector< int > v2;
    v2.push_back(20);
    v2.push_back(40);
    v2.push_back(60);

    ds.add(120, v2);

    std::cout << "------------ keys ---------------" << std::endl;
    for (DS::KeyIter it = ds.beginKey(); it != ds.endKey(); ++it) {
        std::cout << (*it) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "------------ values ---------------" << std::endl;
    // std::cout << (*(ds.beginValue())) << std::endl;
    for (DS::ValueIter it = ds.beginValue(); it != ds.endValue(); ++it) {
        std::cout << (*it) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented in c++11. You should be able to do the conversion to boost/c++03 fairly simply.

This iterator is FORWARD ONLY and it's quite fragile (see the comparison operator).

user discretion advised.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::vector< int > IntList;
typedef std::unordered_map< int, IntList* > Map;

struct whole_map_const_iterator
{
    using C1 = IntList;
    using C2 = Map;

    using I1 = C1::const_iterator;
    using I2 = C2::const_iterator;

    using value_type = I1::value_type;
    using reference = I1::reference;

    whole_map_const_iterator(I2 i2) : _i2(i2) {}

    bool operator==(const whole_map_const_iterator& r) const {
        if (_i2 != r._i2)
            return false;

        if (deferred_i1 && r.deferred_i1)
            return true;

        if (deferred_i1 != r.deferred_i1)
            return false;

        return _i1 == r._i1;
    }
    bool operator!=(const whole_map_const_iterator& r) const { return !(*this == r); }

    reference operator*() const {
        check_deferred();
        return *_i1;
    }

    void check_deferred() const {
        if (deferred_i1) {
            _i1 = _i2->second->begin();
            _i1limit = _i2->second->end();
            deferred_i1 = false;
        }
    }

    void go_next()
    {
        check_deferred();
        if (++_i1 == _i1limit) {
            ++_i2;
            deferred_i1 = true;
        }
    }

    whole_map_const_iterator& operator++() {
        go_next();
        return *this;
    }

    whole_map_const_iterator operator++(int) {
        auto result = *this;
        go_next();
        return result;
    }

    I2 _i2;
    mutable I1 _i1 = {}, _i1limit = {};
    mutable bool deferred_i1 = true;

};

IntList a { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IntList b { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
Map m { { 1, &a }, { 2, &b } };


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto from = whole_map_const_iterator(m.begin());
    auto to = whole_map_const_iterator(m.end());
    for ( ; from != to ; ++from) {
        std::cout << *from << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
```

For bonus points, answer this question:

Q: Why all that damn complication over the deferred flag?

Comment: Deferred flag is used for managing the list/vector iterator. If it's reached the end, but the map iterator hasn't reached the end, readjust it for next key.